# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect - Complicated type in JSON POST body

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Using Spring 4 and Jackson 2.x

I'm posting the following JSON to the following controller method. When I post it with the `grantedAuthorities` filled out with one entry, then I get a `400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.` response.

```
headers:273 - >> POST /rest/users HTTP/1.1
headers:276 - >> Accept: */*
headers:276 - >> Content-Length: 103
headers:276 - >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
headers:276 - >> Host: localhost:8090
headers:276 - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
headers:276 - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)
headers:276 - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
wire:77 - >> "{"password":"Password","id":0,"username":"Amy","grantedAuthorities":[{"role":"RANDOM_FAKE_AUTHORITY"}]}"
```

If I put this in the body, with no granted authorities in the List of granted authorities, it works fine.

```
{"password":"Password","id":0,"username":"Mike","grantedAuthorities":[]}
```

I have `Jackson 2.0` on my classpath, so I assume that's what it's using to map these Json bodies to objects. I'm just not sure why jackson is choking on the granted authorities, or refusing to process them. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Controller
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseWithView<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return new ResponseWithView<>(userService.save(user), Views.Public.class);
    }

User class that the JSON should be mapping to.
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Accessors(chain=true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"username"})
    public class User implements Motherly {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
        private int id;
        @Column(unique = true)
        @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
        private String username;
        private String password;
        @JsonView(Views.Admin.class)
        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;
```

GrantedAuthority is an interface from Spring.

```
public interface GrantedAuthority extends Serializable {
    String getAuthority();
}
```

In my code I always use the implementation SimpleGrantedAuthority

```
public final class SimpleGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    private final String role;

    public SimpleGrantedAuthority(String role) {
        Assert.hasText(role, "A granted authority textual representation is required");
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return role;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {


   return true;
        }

        if (obj instanceof SimpleGrantedAuthority) {
            return role.equals(((SimpleGrantedAuthority) obj).role);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return this.role.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.role;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussion in comments/chat found that problem was Jackson didn't like the missing empty constructor which doesn't exist since you specified one

```
// add this constructor
public SimpleGrantedAuthority() { 
}

public SimpleGrantedAuthority(String role) {
  Assert.hasText(role, "A granted authority textual representation is required");
  this.role = role;
}
```

Comment: In the code there is a declaration for a List object, parameterized by the GranteAuthority> class. private List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities; I'm not sure how what you've posted is different besides dropping the type safety.

Comment: [{"role":"RANDOM_FAKE_AUTHORITY"}] is different than {"role":"RANDOM_FAKE_AUTHORITY"}

Comment: Woops. I typed something wrong in the question. Was never sending the  version without the []'s. Corrected question now.

Comment: can you post your GrantedAuthority.class ?

Comment: It's a spring class, but I've included it

Comment: since GrantedAuthority is an interface and doesn't actually have the role field, you might need to either create a new class, use  SimpleGrantedAuthority as your List type, or create a custom mapper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61085/discussion-between-nick-and-jazzepi).